# Autonumber field in SQL Database CE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Is there anything like Autonumber field in SQL server CE database file, like we have in Access?  I want to get it incremented automatically.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[IDENTITY Property (SQL Server Compact Edition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use IDENTITY:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
   ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
```

)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Tool(
   ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IDENTITY :

```
CREATE TABLE t_test(
 id INTEGER IDENTITY
      PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(10)
 );
```